# Value of $c$ for which Continuity holds in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm given a function $f(x,y)$ and have to determine the value of $c$ for which it is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$

$$f(x,y)=$$
\begin{cases}  \sqrt{1-x^2-4y^2} & \text{if $x^2+4y^2\leq 1$} \\ c & \text{if $x^2+4y^2 \gt  1$} \end{cases}
How can I find the vaue of $c$ .Please help with this...

Comment: take the sequences $({n-1\over n},0)$ and $({n+1\over n},0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2}$, then its projections $f_1 = f(x,0)$, and $f_2 = f(0,y)$ must be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. We have: $f_1 = \sqrt{1-x^2}, x^2 \leq 1$, and $f_1 = c, x^2 > 1$. And $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f_1 = 0 = \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} f_1 = c$. We have $c = 0$.

Comment: thanks for the nice answer...